# how do I create a .jar to run command line application

Tags: java, jar

For ease I'll use hello world...

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main (String [] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Compiles and runs fine as you'd imagine. Then made a file Manifest.txt containing:

```
Main-Class: HelloWorld
```

then ran:

```
jar -cfm Hello.jar Manifest.txt *.class
```

However when I double click the resulting Hello.jar, nothing happens. I'd expect the console to pop up quickly at least...
(I in fact have a more elaborate program which waits for input)

Any ideas why this is not working?

It is starting a process in the task manager (windows) but no cmd openning

Comment: What happens when you run the program from the command line with `java -jar Hello.jar`?

Comment: But I want to send my jar to someone who is useless with computers. I need a double click to work

Comment: Well, I just asked what happens if you run it from the command line. Do you get any errors in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing from command line

```
java -jar /path/to/YourJar.jar
```

Make sure you have `Main-Class` entry

---

**See Also**

- [Running jar file as application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html)

Comment: ok that works, but I want to send my jar to someone who is useless with computers. I need a double click to work

Comment: Well you need your client to have JRE to run that jar.. you can also set up default program to open `.jar` file as `JRE` depending on OS.

Comment: press shift and right click on your jar file, now select _open with_ , select java run time as default program now double click it simply, OS will load the jar on JRE now by default

Comment: now at least I get cmd to pop up. but it says `Error :could not find or load main class: /path/to/myjar.jar`

Comment: Just put both the jar you need to run and a batch file containing only the line of code in his answer ("java -jar jarname.jar") on one line, and tell the user to double click the batch file.

Comment: batch file... a suitable solution... but would still like to be able to use .jar files

Comment: your `manifest.mf` file should have `Main-class:YourMainClass` entry

Answer (score 2):

make sure the `Main-Class` line in the manifest file is followed by an empty line!
Hard to believe, but the specification mandates that each line of the manifest file, including the last one, be terminated by a newline character.

EDIT:
If the problem is just with double clicking, try (assuming Windows):

```
assoc .jar=jarfile
ftype jarfile="<JRE directory>\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

*(use these without argument to check the actual settings)*

Your clients will need the JRE to run the Java program - the above settings normally are done by the installation of the JRE.

EDIT2:
Use `java.exe` instead of `javaw.exe` to see the standard console (if your program does not have a GUI)

Comment: after checking task manager , it is starting a javaw.exe process.. but no cmd is openning

Comment: javaw is java windowless. There won't be a *window* visible ;)

Comment: @Mead3000 - added more info. Does your program have a GUI?

Comment: ook... changed it to java.exe... cmd pops up saying `Error: cannot find or load Main class: /path/to/jar.jar`

Comment: when you double click it? I am pretty sure that `jar.jar` is *not* the name of the JAR file!

Comment: @Mead3000 - this error indicates that your manifest Main-Class is wrong (`Main-Class: /path/to/Hello.jar` instead of `Main-Class: HelloWorld`)

Comment: I though I have to specify the the class my main method is in? :s

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6166/discussion-between-carlos-heuberger-and-mead3000)

Answer (score 0):

The manifest needs to be named MANIFEST.MF and it needs to reside in a top level directory called META-INF. Then it should work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that those are created when the jar is created. jar -tf Hello.jar gives me that

Answer (score 0):

You should give [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) a try. It takes your jar file and wraps it into a Windows executable.